# Download a (large) file: simple redirect vs. download helper

Tags: codeigniter

I have a question about making a download system. I have made one in the past, but it was very basic. What I did was adding the filename of the download to the database:

```
id | title     | filename
---|-----------|--------------
 1 | Something | something.zip
```

Then when a user visits download.php?id=1 he will simply be redirected to: */path/to/downloads/something.zip* by using:

```
header('Location: /path/to/downloads/something.zip');
```

This causes the brower to automatically start the download. But is it ok to do it this way? I'm building a downloadsystem with Codeigniter, and there's a download helper available. To provide a download, I would need:

```
$data = file_get_contents('/path/to/downloads/something.zip');
$name = 'Something';

force_download($name, $data);
```

I noticed that the download is slower this way, compared to the simple redirect, due to the file_get_contents(). I have some large downloads (up to 1 GB size). What do you suggest? Should I use the Codeigniter download helper, use a redirect directly to the file or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)

```
function downloadFile( $fullPath ){ 

// Must be fresh start 
if( headers_sent() ) 
die('Headers Sent'); 

// Required for some browsers 
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) 
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); 

// File Exists? 
if( file_exists($fullPath) ){ 

// Parse Info / Get Extension 
$fsize = filesize($fullPath); 
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath); 
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]); 

// Determine Content Type 
switch ($ext) { 
   case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break; 
   case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break; 
   case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break; 
   case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break; 
   case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break; 
   case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break; 
   case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break; 
   case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break; 
   case "jpeg": 
   case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break; 
   default: $ctype="application/force-download"; 
} 

header("Pragma: public"); // required 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: $ctype"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" ); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize); 
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile( $fullPath ); 

} else die('File Not Found'); 

}
```

Comment: Can also use CodeIgniter's `mimes.php` located in config folder

Comment: Yes, but that is more or less the same as the Codeigniter force_download function. My question actually is: why isn't a redirect to the file directly not ok? The file will be downloaded too.

Comment: Because you loose the whole point of the topic, the user will see the URL to the file.

Comment: If that's not what you need, and you simply want to add some event when the download begins, then it might do the job

Comment: I thought there could be other reasons to use those methods, e.g. security or so. I'll just go with the force_download function, might be more secure to hide the exact file location.